# Properties and instance variable declaration

Tags: objective-c

I notice that you can 'double declare' a variable in this way:

```
@interface A {
    NSString *instanceVariable;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *instanceVariable;
@end
```

This has the same effect that just do:

```
@interface A {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *instanceVariable;
@end
```

Why doesn't the compiler complain in situations like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because both ways are valid.

Declaring ivar via just declaring a property for it is a new language feature available starting objc 2.0

In ["Run-time differences"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW3) section of "Objective-c programming language" reference stated:

> For @synthesize to work in the legacy
>   runtime, you must either provide an
>   instance variable with the same name
>   and compatible type of the property or
>   specify another existing instance
>   variable in the @synthesize statement.
>   With the modern runtime, if you do not
>   provide an instance variable, the
>   compiler adds one for you.

Comment: ...trying to find a prooflink meanwhile :)

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9) ... *"For the modern runtimes [...], instance variables are synthesized as needed. If an instance variable of the same name already exists, it is used."*