# Whats the difference between property and property with instance variable?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Properties and instance variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736677/properties-and-instance-variable-declaration)

Whats the difference between the following two:

SomeClass.h

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
     NSString *someString;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *someString;
@end
```

SomeClass.h

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *someString;

@end
```

I know whats the difference between the declaration inside the { } after the interface and a property is, but whats the difference between using both and using just a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the LLVM version 4.2 compiler there is no longer a difference. You no longer HAVE to declare a property variable inside the {}.

Comment: This is not since iOS 5. This is since the LLVM version 4.2 compiler started being used. This is not an iOS feature. It is a compiler feature.

Comment: I would trust rmaddy on this. I only say io5 because that's when I noticed that you no longer needed it. Updating answer to reflect this.

Comment: @rmaddy : i wonder if inside the { & } are protected, please comment of this?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I forget what the default scope is for ivars declared in the interface. I put all ivars in the `@implementation` block so they are always private. If you have some reason to keep the ivars in the `@interface` block, at least precede them with `@private` to ensure they are private.

Comment: No as MechIntel didnt mention and just says no longer any differnce, So I just wanted to confirm, there are still few differences, and his answer is not 100% correct!!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya It is correct in context of the question being asked. He said he already knows what it means to not have the property tag. He wants to know what it means not to declare the ivar. The answer to that question is that there is no difference.

Comment: one (in context of iOS rather academic) reason for not declaring ivars at all: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html

Answer (score 1):

```
{
     NSString *someString;
}
```

This is an ivar.

---

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *someString;
```

This is a property which creates setter and getter (accessors). Also one class instance with same name is created for you.

EDIT:

If you only use ivar, you cant use self.ivar name.

You have to use by _ivar, means directly to the ivar.

Inside { & } are protected. While @property are public.

Comment: Yes I knew that. I just didn't knew the difference between only using a property and using both. As MechIntel stated its the same.

Comment: @c2programming : did you check my edit?